# Model's attribute not getting updated on change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to bind status message to variable. If it's empty I need to hide div. If it's not empty show div and message. At the moment when I update `$scope.statusMessage.msg`in controller the `{{statusMessage.msg}}` is not being updated. How to fix it?

```
<div class="alert alert-info"
     ng-class="{'alert-danger': statusMessage.status == -1, 'alert-success': statusMessage.status == 1, 'alert-warning': statusMessage.status == 0}"
     role="alert"  ng-hide="(statusMessage.msg).length == 0">{{statusMessage.msg}}</div>

$scope.statusButtonAction = function(action){
    $scope.statusMessage.msg = 'Validation Error';
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
<form role="form" class="form-inline" id="status-buttons">             
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" ng-click="statusButtonAction('Validation Error')">Validation Error</button>
</form>
```

**UPDATE 2**
declaration of :

```
$scope.statusMessage = {
    msg: '',
    status: null
};
```

**UPDATE 3**

http://jsbin.com/jaquc/2/

**UPDATE 4**

I use https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router . and my config is :

```
 prototypeApplication.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('welcome', {
        url: '/',
        views: {
            '': {
                templateUrl: 'views/prototype/welcome.html',
                controller: 'welcomeController'
            },
            'header@welcome': {
                templateUrl: 'views/components/header.html'
            },
            'check-in@welcome': {
                templateUrl: 'views/prototype/welcome/check-in.html',
                controller: 'checkInController'

            },
            'status-buttons@welcome': {
                templateUrl: 'views/prototype/welcome/status-buttons.html',
                controller: 'checkInController'
            }

        }
    })
```

**UPDATE 5**

Strange enough, but when I switch from object oriented representation to plain variables all works:

```
$scope.statusMessage = '123';
$scope.statusState = null;
```

Does it mean I have to use some trick to make AngularJS read object's property's values?

Comment: `ng-hide="statusMessage.msg == '' "`

Comment: please provide a jsFiddle or a plnkr ...

Comment: Can you show us how you call statusButtonAction?

Comment: In the linked example the `action` parameter is `undefined`. This means that the `statusMessage.msg` is not set. Removing the `switch` block and always setting `statusMessage.msg` updates `$scope` as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that editing **ui-router** configuration like this solves the problem

```
...
check-in@welcome': {
                templateUrl: 'views/prototype/welcome/check-in.html' 
/*,
                controller: 'checkInController' */ // should be removed to work!
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you defined  `$scope.statusMessage` ie:

```
$scope.statusMessage = {};
```

before you try set $scope.statusMessage.msg in your statusButtonAction function.

and use
`ng-hide="!statusMessage.msg"` or `ng-show="statusMessage.msg"`
 instead
`ng-hide="(statusMessage.msg).length == 0"`

Please see working demo here http://jsbin.com/vavahi/1/edit

Comment: When I debug in Chrome it shows that $scope.statusMessage.msg gets new value but `hide` directive keep hiding it and nothing changes in `{{statusMessage.msg}}`

Comment: @Rcola ng-hide="!statusMessage.msg"

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is use of '==' instead of '==='. The former does type coercion and results are a bit 'unreliable' especially with strings/arrays... At least I use ng-hide="myArray.length === 0" as the way to control  and works always as it should.

(However, I am not sure what you are trying to do in your ng-class with "... == -1" etc. - at least I don't see statusMessage.status being declared nor used in your code...)